TagsInput in Mantine Core Not Working with Mobile Keyboard in Mobile Browser
I am implementing a feature in my NextJS app that uses Mantine Core for most of the UI. So, I have a form input that accepts mobile numbers and when the user enters a semi-colon, comma, space, or enter, the number is converted to a tag and the input is ready to accept the next mobile number. This works well in desktop browsers, but I noticed in mobile browsers, these inputs, i.e. semicolon, space, or comma are not detected hence numbers are not converted to tags. Here is my component:
<TagsInput
                    label="Enter Mobile Numbers"
                    placeholder="Enter mobile numbers separated with a comma, semicolon, or space"
                    splitChars={[",", " ", ";"]}
                    clearable
                    style={{ width: "100%" }}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={setValue}
                    inputMode="tel"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    enterKeyHint="done"
                />

Is there something I am missing with this component that will make it work with the Mobile browser? Note that I tried adding the enterKeyHint="done" at least to activate the ENTER command on the mobile keyboard, but instead, it shows NEXT when in that field.
